# AppleScript - Repeat While with Return

Tags: applescript

My goal is to run a script continuously for 10 seconds, returning the result while the script runs.  Right now when I run the script below the script stops after returning the result.  If I remove the "return result" line it runs continuously for 10 seconds.  How do I get it to return the result, then keep running the script until the 10 seconds is up.

```
set start_value to do shell script "ruby -e 'print Time.now.to_f'"
repeat while true
    set end_value to do shell script "ruby -e 'print Time.now.to_f'"
    #display dialog "hello"

    do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & "GoPro Player" & "$/ {print $1}'"
    set GoProUsage to (do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & "GoPro Player" & "$/ {print $1}'") as integer 
    return result
    if end_value - start_value ≥ 10 then
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: `return` does just that - it returns from the script (or handler).  Regular AppleScript only runs in a single thread - what are you wanting to send the results to?

Comment: @KevinGrabher Questions about AppleScript are perfectly ontopic on AD, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What do you want to do with the value assigned to "GoProUsage"?